# OFFSET FETCH unexpected results when PRIMARY KEY is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, fetch, offset

**Synopsis:**
When querying a table that uses a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (populated using `newsequentialid()`) for its primary key, `OFFSET / FETCH` seems to return inaccurate results if records are inserted that have out of order keys.

I recently implemented a solution using an Entity Attribute Value pattern for a SQL Server table. I created a data layer utilizing the Entity Framework for paged data access. The only relevance of mentioning the Entity Framework is that it is what is responsible for creating the `OFFSET / FETCH` SQL statements that I will be discussing. I'm aware of alternative solutions that could be implemented that work without using `OFFSET / FETCH`, however, this is not the intent of my post. The intent of this post is to understand exactly what is happening with the `OFFSET / FETCH` query.

I'm including the necessary SQL required to replicate this issue.

The following SQL statement will create a Table that implements the EAV pattern:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OptionalValues]
(
     [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_OptionalValues_Id] DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
     [Type] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
     [Name] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
     [Value] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_OptionalValues] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The following statements will insert test data into the table:

```
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'04c9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Eyes', N'Eyes');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'05c9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Skin', N'Skin');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'06c9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Autonomic Nervous System', N'Autonomic Nervous System');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'07c9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Kidneys', N'Kidneys');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'08c9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Liver', N'Liver');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'09c9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Respiratory System', N'Respiratory System');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'0ac9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Lungs', N'Lungs');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'0bc9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Central Nervous System', N'Central Nervous System');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'0cc9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Blood', N'Blood');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'0dc9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Heart', N'Heart');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'0ec9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Reproductive System', N'Reproductive System');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value])  
VALUES (N'0fc9f78a-5114-e711-90c2-005056a9316b', N'TargetOrgans', N'Cardiovascular System', N'Cardiovascular System');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'd6fdf6b9-6014-e711-815c-080027f9bf3f', N'TargetOrgans', N'TEST_ONE', N'TEST_ONE');
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'5a8c5533-6114-e711-815c-080027f9bf3f', N'TargetOrgans', N'TEST_TWO', N'TEST_TWO')
INSERT [dbo].[OptionalValues] ([Id], [Type], [Name], [Value]) 
VALUES (N'801a12da-6214-e711-815c-080027f9bf3f', N'TargetOrgans', N'TEST_THREE', N'TEST_THREE');
```

The last three records inserted have [Id] values that were **NOT** generated by the table's `newsequentialid()` function and are out of sync with the other records.

This query will return all 15 records, including the records that have "out of sequence" id's

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[OptionalValues] 
ORDER BY [Type]
```

The next 3 queries are the ones that don't make sense to me. They include an ORDER BY [Type] which is **NOT** unique, and do **NOT** include any explicit [Id] ordering

This query does **NOT** show records that have "out of sequence" id's

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[OptionalValues] 
ORDER BY [Type] 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

This query does **NOT** show records that have "out of sequence" id's even though the result count is still 15???

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[OptionalValues] 
ORDER BY [Type] 
    OFFSET 10 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

This query shows all 15 records including rows that have "out of sequence" id's

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[OptionalValues] 
ORDER BY [Type] 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```

The "fix" is to add a truly unique sort using the [Id] column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[OptionalValues] 
ORDER BY [Type], [Id] 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY

SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[OptionalValues] 
ORDER BY [Type], [Id] 
    OFFSET 10 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

My question really surrounds the inaccuracy of the queries that do not have truly unique sort. Why do the queries seemingly recognize the records with an "out of sequence id" in the paged row count, but those records are not shown in the query results? Does the Index created in conjunction with the Primary Key affect the sort behavior of the previous queries in any way?

Thank you for any assistance and clarification that you can provide.

Comment: Sql server does not guarantee the order of the results when the order by clause is missing, or when the columns specified in the order by clause contains duplicated values. The order you see now can change the next time you run the query.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is *the* mechanism by which you express your ordering requirements. If you fail to *request* a deterministic ordering, SQL Server can hardly be faulted for not matching your expectations. The mechanism is right there are you chose to ignore it.

Comment: Also, the data type of the primary key is irrelevant to this question. Even the data type of the clustered index is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and Zohar-Peled - Thanks for the reply. What I don't understand is that when the deterministic ordering is removed, in this case... SQL Server is not "randomly" sequencing the results... it is very consistently ignoring the records that have an [Id] that were not generated by the newsequentialid() function. I can run and re-run the queries without deterministic ordering and consistently get back the exact same result set. 
If the order is not truly random, then what influences the order?

Comment: @Zohar-Peled - Thanks for the reply. When you run the non-deterministic queries, do you get different results? Every time I run them, I get the exact same result set... which does NOT include records with [Id]'s generated by the newsequentialid() function. Is it possible that I could have a setting or configuration issue that is affecting the determinism of my query results? I'm testing using an OOTB SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition and OOTB SSMS. To the best of my knowledge, everything is vanilla.

Comment: If, every morning, you pass a red car, followed by a green car, followed by a blue car, that doesn't mean that those drivers are contractually obligated to always follow the same driving plan. Observed behaviour is not a suitable guide to *guaranteed* behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql server does not guarantee the order of the results when the order by clause is missing, or when the columns specified in the order by clause contains duplicated values.   This **does not** mean that the order of the rows is random, It just means it is not something you can trust being consistant. This is true, btw, to any relational database. Tables are un ordered by nature.
It's also the reason why you must specify the `order by` clause when you are using the `offset...fetch next` clause, and why you can't use `order by` in views, derived tables or a cte without using `top` or `offset...fetch next`.

Comment: Would it be correct to make the following statement:

Comment: Deterministic == Not Random
Non-Deterministic != Random (Does not necessarily equal)

I think the latter is what has been confusing me. I've been running the non-deterministic queries with the expectation that I would "see" varying results because SQL Server does not guarantee the order of results. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever states... "Observed behaviour is not a suitable guide to guaranteed behaviour"... which makes me believe that my expectation of observing varying results is what is out of alignment.